# How to not allow Many2many to be able to remove its element in form view?

Tags: odoo

I have a many2many field that represents a list of student. I want to only add student to that list but not remove any students from that list (in form view). Is it possible to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to do it. You need to override the `@write` method. Each time that an update will be made on your object, you need the compare the actual length of your many2many field `current_length` and the new length of students made by the update `new_length`.

If `new_length > current_length`, it's means that the update is an adding, so you can consider the changes. Otherwise, it's means that the update is a removing, so you just need to ignore the changes.

Please find below, an exemple of implementation :

```
@api.multi
def write(self, values):
    current_length = len(self.student_list)
    new_length = len(values['student_list'])
    if current_length > new_length:
       \* Removing of students *\
       values['student_list'] = self.student_list

    res = super(Object, self).write(values)
    return res
```

Note that you can go further by making another comparaison between the ids of the current and new list, in order to be sure that the students are the same.

Comment: The length check is wrong when there are still removals but you have more additions than removals isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It s not possible using the many2many_tags widget, but using the xml tree view as part of your Form view, you can add the delete-attribute on the tree-node inside the scope of your own field:

```xml
<form>
<notebook>
<sheet>
<page string="Graduated" name="gratuated_students">
    <field name="students_ids" >        
        <tree string="Students" editable="bottom"  delete="0" >    
                <field name="name"/>                   
                <field name="birthday"/>
                <field name="score" readonly="1"/>
         </tree>
    </field>
</page>
</notebook>
</sheet>
</form>
```

If this view comes from an odoo's module (no custom module): you'd rather inherit this view and add the attribute "delete=0" to the existing student_ids field:

```xml
<xpath expr="//form[1]/sheet[1]/notebook[1]/page[1]/field[@name='students_ids']/tree[1]" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="delete">0</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Otherwise, if you really want to use the many2many_tags widget and if your are experienced with odoo's js-framework, you could develop your own option "no_delete" on the basis of the following OCA module:
https://odoo-community.org/shop/web-m2x-options-2661#attr=10772

Comment: I've tried this method but I can still remove elements from the many2many field (by clicking the x symbol then hitting save) when editing the record.